# Mock with flowOf as a parameter

Tags: kotlin, junit, mockito, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I have a function with one of the parameter like this:

`idList: Flow<List<String>?> = flowOf(null)`

When I try to mock it like this `every { someFun(org.mockito.kotlin.anyOrNull()) }`

It doesn't work because when I pass null in that parameter, the function creates a new FlowKt object with a different id than in the mock any()

How to mock that call?

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal reproducable example? What is the definition of `someFun`, has it overloads?